# Operator Overloading with C# Extension Methods

Tags: c#, extension-methods, operator-overloading

I'm attempting to use extension methods to add an operater overload to the C# `StringBuilder` class.  Specifically, given `StringBuilder` `sb`, I'd like `sb += "text"` to become equivalent to `sb.Append("text")`.

Here's the syntax for creating an extension method for `StringBuilder`:

```
public static class sbExtensions
{
    public static StringBuilder blah(this StringBuilder sb)
    {
        return sb;
    }
}
```

It successfully adds the `blah` extension method to the `StringBuilder`.

Unfortunately, operator overloading does not seem to work:

```
public static class sbExtensions
{
    public static StringBuilder operator +(this StringBuilder sb, string s)
    {
        return sb.Append(s);
    }
}
```

Among other issues, the keyword `this` is not allowed in this context.

Are adding operator overloads via extension methods possible?  If so, what's the proper way to go about it?

Comment: Although this at first seems like a cool idea, consider var otherSb = sb + "hi";

Answer (score 165, accepted):

This is not currently possible, because extension methods must be in static classes, and static classes can't have operator overloads. But the [feature is being discussed for *some* future release of C#](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/192). Mads talked a bit more about implementing it [in this video from 2017](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Seth-Juarez/A-Preview-of-C-8-with-Mads-Torgersen#time=32m11s).

On why it isn't currently implemented, Mads Torgersen, C# Language PM says:

> ...for the Orcas release we decided to
> take the cautious approach and add
> only regular extension methods, as
> opposed to extention properties,
> events, operators, static methods, etc
> etc. Regular extension methods were
> what we needed for LINQ, and they had
> a syntactically minimal design that
> could not be easily mimicked for some
> of the other member kinds.
>
> We are becoming increasingly aware
> that other kinds of extension members
> could be useful, and so we will return
> to this issue after Orcas. No
> guarantees, though!

Further below in the same article:

> I am sorry to report that we will not
> be doing this in the next release. We
> did take extension members very
> seriously in our plans, and spent a
> lot of effort trying to get them
> right, but in the end we couldn't get
> it smooth enough, and decided to give
> way to other interesting features.
>
> This is still on our radar for future
> releases. What will help is if we get
> a good amount of compelling scenarios
> that can help drive the right design.

Comment: This page has since been taken down; this issue is still not resolved.

Comment: Too bad. I just wanted to add an operator to multiply a TimeSpan by a scalar value... :(

Comment: I was hoping to implement this same concept to cast a `String` to a PowerShell `ScriptBlock`.

Comment: That means I can't overload % to be xor betwen booleans? :(    
dead at `true.Xor(false)` then

Comment: @SparK `^` is the xor operator in C#

Comment: @JacobKrall Hmmm I tought it was only bitwise and not a logical operator too. Thanks!

Comment: Is this still unders consideration? It seems that it's still not possible to overload operators using extension methods.

Comment: @SuperJMN yes, still under consideration, but not for c# 8.0. It didn't make the cut

Comment: Probably not in C# 9 either ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9

Comment: Any updates for 22-23?

Answer (score 63):

If you control the places where you want to use this "extension operator" (which you normally do with extension methods anyway), you can do something like this:

```
class Program {

  static void Main(string[] args) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    ReceiveImportantMessage(sb);
    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
  }

  // the important thing is to use StringBuilderWrapper!
  private static void ReceiveImportantMessage(StringBuilderWrapper sb) {
    sb += "Hello World!";
  }

}

public class StringBuilderWrapper {

  public StringBuilderWrapper(StringBuilder sb) { StringBuilder = sb; }
  public StringBuilder StringBuilder { get; private set; }

  public static implicit operator StringBuilderWrapper(StringBuilder sb) {
    return new StringBuilderWrapper(sb);
  }

  public static StringBuilderWrapper operator +(StringBuilderWrapper sbw, string s) { 
      sbw.StringBuilder.Append(s);
      return sbw;
  }

}
```

The `StringBuilderWrapper` class declares an [implicit conversion operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx) from a `StringBuilder` *and* declares the desired `+` operator. This way, a `StringBuilder` can be passed to `ReceiveImportantMessage`, which will be silently converted to a `StringBuilderWrapper`, where the `+` operator can be used.

To make this fact more transparent to callers, you can declare `ReceiveImportantMessage` as taking a `StringBuilder` and just use code like this:

```
  private static void ReceiveImportantMessage(StringBuilder sb) {
    StringBuilderWrapper sbw = sb;
    sbw += "Hello World!";
  }
```

Or, to use it inline where you're already using a `StringBuilder`, you can simply do this:

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 StringBuilderWrapper sbw = sb;
 sbw += "Hello World!";
 Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

I created [a post](http://codecrafter.blogspot.com/2010/04/more-understandable-icomparable.html) about using a similar approach to make `IComparable` more understandable.

Comment: I think you meant that StringBuilderWrapper should inherit StringBuilder ?

Comment: @Leon: I really meant to compose it, not inherit from it. Anyway, I couldn't inherit from it since it's sealed.

Comment: fair enough, but you're passing a StringBuilder to ReceiveImportantMessage, which expects a StringBuilderWrapper

Comment: @Leon: That's the heart of this technique. I can do that because there's an [implicit conversion operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx) declared in `StringBuilderWrapper` that makes it possible.

Comment: This is required to create a new type, and cannot be used with literals like " " .

Comment: @pylover: You're right, this requires creating a new type, that will wrap the `StringBuilder` type and provide an implicit conversion operator from it. After that, it _can_ be used with string literals, as demonstrated in the example: `sb += "Hello World!";`

Comment: @Jordão: Yes, But i wish to overload the `*`operator for string literal, and use it in T4 templates like `PushIndent(" " * 4)` just like the python.

Comment: May I suggest then, to add an extension method to `String`: `PushIndent(" ".X(4))` (could also be called `Times`). Or maybe using this constructor: `PushIndent(new String(' ', 4))`.

Comment: @Jordão: Great answer ;)

Comment: Great answer, ty!!

Comment: Suggest also overloading "*" to perform AppendLine().

Answer (score 8):

It appears this isn't currently possible - there's an open feedback issue requesting this very feature on Microsoft Connect:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=168224

suggesting it might appear in a future release but isn't implemented for the current version.

Comment: What exactly do you mean, "isn't currently possible?" It must be possible in the CLR because F# supports extension everything.

Comment: I think he means that it is not possible in C#, not the CLR. The whole extension methods thing is a C# compiler trick anyway.

Comment: Link is dead now.

Answer (score 2):

Though it's not possible to do the operators, you could always just create Add (or Concat), Subtract, and Compare methods....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;    

namespace Whatever.Test
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static int Compare(this MyObject t1, MyObject t2)
        {
            if(t1.SomeValueField < t2.SomeValueField )
                return -1;
            else if (t1.SomeValueField > t2.SomeValueField )
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        public static MyObject Add(this MyObject t1, MyObject t2)
        {
            var newObject = new MyObject();
            //do something  
            return newObject;

        }

        public static MyObject Subtract(this MyObject t1, MyObject t2)
        {
            var newObject= new MyObject();
            //do something
            return newObject;    
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hah! I was looking up "extension operator overloading" with exactly the same desire, for `sb += (thing)`.

After reading the answers here (and seeing that the answer is "no"), for my particular needs, I went with an extension method which combines `sb.AppendLine` and `sb.AppendFormat`, and looks tidier than either.

```
public static class SomeExtensions
{
    public static void Line(this StringBuilder sb, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        string s = String.Format(format + "\n", args);
        sb.Append(s);
    }
}
```

And so,

```
sb.Line("the first thing is {0}", first);
sb.Line("the second thing is {0}", second);
```

Not a general answer, but may be of interest to future seekers looking at this kind of thing.

Comment: I think your extension method would read better if you named it `AppendLine` instead of `Line`.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to rigg it with a wrapper and extensions but impossible to do it properly. You end with garbage which totally defeats the purpose.
I have a post up somewhere on here that does it, but its worthless.

Btw 
All numeric conversions create garbage in string builder that needs to be fixed. I had to write a wrapper for that which does work and i use it. That is worth perusing.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers still seem to be correct, this is not implemented in C#. You can, however, get very close with a little more code.

#### Option 1, wrapper class around StringBuilder

Something like this:

```cs
public static class ExtStringBuilder
{
    public class WStringBuilder
    {
        private StringBuilder _sb { get; }
        public WStringBuilder(StringBuilder sb) => _sb = sb;
        public static implicit operator StringBuilder(WStringBuilder sbw) => sbw._sb;
        public static implicit operator WStringBuilder(StringBuilder sb) => new WStringBuilder(sb);
        public static WStringBuilder operator +(WStringBuilder sbw, string s) => sbw._sb.Append(s);
    }
    public static WStringBuilder wrap(this StringBuilder sb) => sb;
}
```

usage like this:

```cs
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
// requires a method call which is inconvenient
sb = sb.wrap() + "string1" + "string2";
```

Or:

```cs
WStringBuilder sbw = new StringBuilder();
sbw = sbw + "string1" + "string2";
// you can pass sbw as a StringBuilder parameter
methodAcceptsStringBuilder(sbw);
// but you cannot call methods on it
// this fails: sbw.Append("string3");
```

You can make a wrapper for `string` instead of `StringBuilder` in the exact same fashion, which might be a better fit, but in this case, you'll be wrapping possibly many `string` objects instead of 1 `StringBuilder` object.

---

As [another answer points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41904854/3277592), this strategy seems to defeat a lot of the purpose of having an operator since depending on the use case, the way you use it changes. So it feels a little awkward.

In this case, I agree, this is far too much overhead just to replace a method like `StringBuilder`'s `Append` method. However, if you are putting something more complicated behind the operator (something requiring a for loop, for instance), you may find this is a convenient solution for your project.