# Overloading the + operator to add two arrays

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

What's wrong with this C# code? I tried to overload the + operator to add two arrays, but got an error message as follows:

One of the parameters of a binary operator must be the containing type.

```
class Program
{
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      const int n = 5;

      int[] a = new int[n] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
      int[] b = new int[n] { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
      int[] c = new int[n];

      // c = Add(a, b);
      c = a + b;

      for (int i = 0; i < c.Length; i++)
      {
        Console.Write("{0} ", c[i]);
      }

      Console.WriteLine();
  }

  public static int[] operator+(int[] x, int[] y)
  // public static int[] Add(int[] x, int[] y)
  {
      int[] z = new int[x.Length];

      for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
      {
        z[i] = x[i] + y[i];
      }

      return (z);
  }
}
```

Comment: The MSDN tutorial page on overloading has more information - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: This may be your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172658/operator-overloading-with-c-extension-methods

Comment: We are considering adding "extension operators" to a hypothetical future version of C#, which would solve your problem. Straw poll: do any of you have AWESOME scenarios for this feature? The more awesome REALISTIC scenarios we can get, the more likely a feature is to be implemented some day. Send 'em my way; you can use the email link on my blog.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Does it mean we will also get "Extension Everything" :)

Comment: How do we do this or should I abandon polymorphism until I am polytheistic?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Operators must be declared inside a "related" class' body. For instance:

```
public class Foo
{
    int X;

    // Legal
    public static int operator+(int x, Foo y);

    // This is not
    public static int operator+(int x, int y);
}
```

Since you don't have access to the implementation of arrays, your best bet would be to either wrap your arrays in your own implementation so you can provide additional operations (and this is the only way to make the operator+ work.

On the other hand, you could define an extension method like:

```
public static class ArrayHelper
{
    public static int[] Add(this int[] x, int[] y) { ... }
}
```

The will still lead to natural calls (`x.Add(y)`) while avoiding to wrap arrays in your own class.

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this:

```
class Program {
  static void Main(string[] args) {
    const int n = 5;

    var a = new int[n] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }.WithOperators();
    var b = new int[n] { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };

    int[] c = a + b;

    for (int i = 0; i < c.Length; i++) {
      Console.Write("{0} ", c[i]);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
  }
}

public static class Int32ArrayExtensions {
  public static Int32ArrayWithOperators WithOperators(this int[] self) {
    return self;
  }
}

public class Int32ArrayWithOperators {
  int[] _array;

  public Int32ArrayWithOperators(int[] array) {
    if (array == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
    _array = array; 
  }

  public static implicit operator Int32ArrayWithOperators(int[] array) {
    return new Int32ArrayWithOperators(array); 
  }
  public static implicit operator int[](Int32ArrayWithOperators wrapper) {
    return wrapper._array;
  }

  public static Int32ArrayWithOperators operator +(Int32ArrayWithOperators left, Int32ArrayWithOperators right) {
    var x = left._array;
    var y = right._array;
    return x.Zip(y, (a, b) => a + b).ToArray();
  }
}
```

Based on a related [post](http://codecrafter.blogspot.com/2010/04/more-understandable-icomparable.html) that I wrote.

Comment: I originally upvoted this, because my first read was this it could allow the compiler to think you had methods defined on the array. However, upon reflection I see that it simply allows you hide the fact that what you did was wrap the array with a layer of indirection. Wrapping the array is an easy and obvious solution to get the + operator, but it introduces other overhead I don't want.

Comment: Yes, wrapping the array is a simple way to get what you want, but it's not the full story. It's the implicit conversion operators that allow you to move from wrapper to array and vice versa more easily. In the end, this is just an idea on how to fake extension operators, but is definitely not perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Its states that one of the parameters to the operator needs to be of the same type as the operator function is a member of. So if the operator function is a member of MyClass on of the parameters needs to be of type MyClass.

```
class MyClass
{
 ...

public static int[] operator+(MyClass x, int[] y)
  // public static int[] Add(int[] x, int[] y)
  {
      int[] z = new int[x.Length];

      for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
      {
        z[i] = x[i] + y[i];
      }

      return (z);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to overload le + operator between type AA and BB, you must do it in the class AA or BB and not in a class named Program (like you did).

Unfortunatly, you **cannot write code in the Array** class.

What you can do is to

- create your own class that implements IList
- and put the + operator on that class.

If you need more detailed implementation, just ask me.

Comment: It's too bad there's no way a class can implement `this[int]` in such a way as to match the behavior of array subscripting (returning a `byref` rather than a value).

Answer (score 1):

You can only add operators to a type that you create yourself. A `int[]` is a built in type you can't add operators to it.

You could create your own class that encapsulates an array, and add the operator to it.