# Extending the "<" and ">" operator for System.Type

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Operator Overloading with C# Extension Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172658/operator-overloading-with-c-sharp-extension-methods)

How can i overload those operators, i feel misunderstood by the compiler.

I think the core problem is that i try to overload an operator as an extension to a class. The type class does not have those operators, so i feel pretty safe in doing so - but my compiler disagrees wildly.

```
    public static class TypeCheck
    {
        public static Boolean ToBool(this Type t1, Type t2)
        {
            //normal extension works
            return true;
        }

        public static Boolean operator > (this Type t1, Type t2)
        {
            //TODO once it compiles
            return fasle;
        }

        public static Boolean operator < (this Type t1, Type t2)
        {
            //TODO once it compiles
            return true;
        }

    }
```

To clarify the domain specifics of those comparisons: `class A : B {}`, `class B {}` and `class C {}`  A is greater than A and greater than B but smaller than the rest. Because A.IsCastableTo(B) and A.IsCastableTo(A);

Comment: You find the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172658/operator-overloading-with-c-sharp-extension-methods

Comment: I don't even understand how one Type can be > or < than another.

Comment: @cadrell0: You could read < as "is more narrow than" or "is more specific than", e.g., if `class B : A` then "B < A".

Comment: That does not follow how any other comparisons with < and > work.  17 is not more specific than 23.  1/1/2012 is not more specific than 3/1/2012.  "ASDF" is not more specific than "QWER".  Further what would `C < B` return when C is defined as `class C { }`.  And if you tell me that should return false, then I would expect either `C > B` or `C == B` to return true.

Comment: I'm with cadrell0, what is the use case here?  Something smells...

Comment: @cadrell0: It's obviously a partial order. And I agree that it's questionable to use the standard < > operators for this; I was just trying to point out that it is possible to define a order on types.

Comment: My project depends on several typechecks in different parts of the system - i wanted a way to gather that responsibility in one place. Typechecking is currently done in several subfunctions that are called within if statements. Using a bool operator i want to get rid of the methods without changing the frame of those if statements. I am refactoring right now... so maybe i will do something different in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the others have said, C# doesn't support extension operators. If you need to do this then you can implement a custom type, something like:

```
public class MyType : Type
{
    private Type internalType;

    public MyType(Type t)
    {
        internalType = t;
    }

    public static Boolean operator >(MyType t1, Type t2)
    {
        //TODO once it compiles
        return false;
    }

    public static Boolean operator <(MyType t1, Type t2)
    {
        //TODO once it compiles
        return true;
    }

    public override Assembly Assembly
    {
        get { return internalType.Assembly; }
    }

    public override string AssemblyQualifiedName
    {
        get { return internalType.AssemblyQualifiedName; }
    }

    public override Type BaseType
    {
        get { return internalType.BaseType; }
    }

    public override string FullName
    {
        get { return internalType.FullName; }
    }

    public override Guid GUID
    {
        get { return internalType.GUID; }
    }

    protected override TypeAttributes GetAttributeFlagsImpl()
    {
        return internalType.Attributes;
    }

    protected override ConstructorInfo GetConstructorImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, CallingConventions callConvention, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
    {
        return internalType.GetConstructor(bindingAttr, binder, callConvention, types, modifiers);
    }

    public override ConstructorInfo[] GetConstructors(BindingFlags bindingAttr)
    {
        return internalType.GetConstructors(bindingAttr);
    }

    public override Type GetElementType()
    {
        return GetElementType();
    }

    public override EventInfo GetEvent(string name, BindingFlags bindingAttr)
    {
        return internalType.GetEvent(name, bindingAttr);
    }

    public override EventInfo[] GetEvents(BindingFlags bindingAttr)
    {
        return internalType.GetEvents(bindingAttr);
    }

    public override FieldInfo GetField(string name, BindingFlags bindingAttr)
    {
        return internalType.GetField(name, bindingAttr);
    }

    public override FieldInfo[] GetFields(BindingFlags bindingAttr)
    {
        return internalType.GetFields(bindingAttr);
    }

    public override Type GetInterface(string name, bool ignoreCase)
    {
        return internalType.GetInterface(name, ignoreCase);
    }

    public override Type[] GetInterfaces()
    {
        return internalType.GetInterfaces();
    }

    public override MemberInfo[] GetMembers(BindingFlags bindingAttr)
    {
        return internalType.GetMembers(bindingAttr);
    }

    protected override MethodInfo GetMethodImpl(string name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, CallingConventions callConvention, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
    {
        return internalType.GetMethod(name, bindingAttr, binder, callConvention, types, modifiers);
    }

    public override MethodInfo[] GetMethods(BindingFlags bindingAttr)
    {
        return internalType.GetMethods(bindingAttr);
    }

    public override Type GetNestedType(string name, BindingFlags bindingAttr)
    {
        return internalType.GetNestedType(name, bindingAttr);
    }

    public override Type[] GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags bindingAttr)
    {
        return internalType.GetNestedTypes(bindingAttr);
    }

    public override PropertyInfo[] GetProperties(BindingFlags bindingAttr)
    {
        return internalType.GetProperties(bindingAttr);
    }

    protected override PropertyInfo GetPropertyImpl(string name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Type returnType, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
    {
        return internalType.GetProperty(name, bindingAttr, binder, returnType, types, modifiers);
    }

    protected override bool HasElementTypeImpl()
    {
        return internalType.HasElementType;
    }

    public override object InvokeMember(string name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, object target, object[] args, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, string[] namedParameters)
    {
        return internalType.InvokeMember(name, invokeAttr, binder, target, args, modifiers, culture, namedParameters);
    }

    protected override bool IsArrayImpl()
    {
        return internalType.IsArray;
    }

    protected override bool IsByRefImpl()
    {
        return internalType.IsByRef;
    }

    protected override bool IsCOMObjectImpl()
    {
        return internalType.IsCOMObject;
    }

    protected override bool IsPointerImpl()
    {
        return internalType.IsPointer;
    }

    protected override bool IsPrimitiveImpl()
    {
        return internalType.IsPrimitive;
    }

    public override Module Module
    {
        get { return internalType.Module; }
    }

    public override string Namespace
    {
        get { return internalType.Namespace; }
    }

    public override Type UnderlyingSystemType
    {
        get { return internalType.UnderlyingSystemType; }
    }

    public override object[] GetCustomAttributes(Type attributeType, bool inherit)
    {
        return internalType.GetCustomAttributes(attributeType, inherit);
    }

    public override object[] GetCustomAttributes(bool inherit)
    {
        return internalType.GetCustomAttributes(inherit);
    }

    public override bool IsDefined(Type attributeType, bool inherit)
    {
        return internalType.IsDefined(attributeType, inherit);
    }

    public override string Name
    {
        get { return internalType.Name; }
    }
}
```

Alternatively it would probably be easier to implement a custom `DynamicObject` (C# 4+) which can delegate the calls.

Answer (score 7):

There are no "extension operators" in C#.

At least one of the operator parameters must be the type the operator is declared in.

Answer (score 1):

You can overload operators in your own classes, but not in *other* classes via the extension method approach.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define operators behaviors as extension methods.
You could do this the same way as DateTime works with `Add()` and `Subtract()`, that are implementable as extension methods if you can't modify the types implementation.

You could also inherit from the type (if possible), and define operators there.