# How to use enums as XName

Tags: c#, enums, linq-to-xml, implicit-conversion, xname

I want to create a new `XElement` or `XAttribute` using an `enum` that stores the values. The constructor of both classes expects `XName` as `name` and `object` as `content`. This means that I can pass an enum as `content` but I need to use `ToString()` to use it in the `name`. Note that `XName` has an implicit operator for `string`.

This works:

```
new XElement(HttpStatusCode.Accepted.ToString(), (int)HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
new XElement(HttpStatusCode.Accepted.ToString(), HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
```

This doesn't work:

```
new XElement(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, (int)HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
```

Any suggestions how an `enum` can be for setting the name of an `XElement`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Enums are not implicitly convertible to strings.

C# does not currently have the capability to define extensions operators either.

An extension method may simplify this:

```
public static class EnumXmlExtensions
{
    public static XElement EncodeXElement(this Enum @enum)
    {
        return new XElement(@enum.ToString());
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
HttpStatusCode.Accepted.EncodeXElement(); // <Accepted />
```

See also:

[Operator Overloading with C# Extension Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172658/operator-overloading-with-c-sharp-extension-methods)

Comment: `@enum.ToString()` works and is shorter. I saw that its implementation uses `InternalFormat()` which in turn uses `GetName()`.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I can think of is creating a utility method that will accept an object and convert it into `XName` and will create respective element/attribute. Something like:

```
    private static XElement NewElement(Enum name, params object[] content)
    {
        if (name == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
        }

        return new XElement(name.ToString(), content);
    }
```