# What is the best way to get a multiple of a TimeSpan

Tags: c#, timespan

There is an operation in a program that will take up to 'n' times longer than another operation (so I need to wait 'n' times longer before failing). The timeout for the other operation is saved as a TimeSpan. How do I get (OtherOperation.TimeSpan * 'n')?

Comment: Easy! Declare it several times (multiple)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are we talking .net?

If so use create a new timespan using timespan.frommilliseconds and pass in the original .totalmilliseconds value multiplied by your constant.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, using your suggestion except ticks instead of milliseconds: `TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromTicks(otherProcess.TimeOut.Ticks * multiplier);`

Answer (score 1):

You might consider writing an extension method, such as:

```
public static class TimeSpanEx
{
    public static TimeSpan MultiplyBy (this TimeSpan t, int multiplier)
    {
        return new TimeSpan(t.Ticks * multiplier);
    }
}
```

Now you can simply call:

```
TimeSpan result = yourtimespan.MultiplyBy(3);
```

As an aside, it would be really nice if one could just overload the `*` operator in an extension method, but [this is currently not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/172666/634824).